# GCM messages Reception in Android Application

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I'm using the GCM library to implement push notifications in my Android application.
The problem is that even thought, both Server Side (Sending GCM messages) and Android registration are good, it seems like my Android application dosen't receive the messages sent !! 
I searched a lot and tried to solve it by differents ways, but still nothing. So, Here's my Application files and Thanks a lot for your help.

- Main :

  ```
  public class Login extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);          
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
  btnGo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnenter);
  btnGo.setOnClickListener(this);
  }
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
  return true;
  }

  public void onClick(View v) {
     if (v==btnGo){
          Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, GCMIntentService.class);
          intent.putExtra("val", "coucou");
          startService(intent);

          Intent intent1 = new Intent(Login.this, MedicoAppliMain.class);
          startActivity(intent1);
                 }
     }
  }
  ```
- Android Manifest :

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.medicoappli"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" >

  <uses-sdk
  android:minSdkVersion="9"
  android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

  <permission
  android:name="com.example.medicoappli.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
  android:protectionLevel="signature" />

  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.example.medicoappli.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />


  <application
  android:name="com.example.medicoappli.MyApp"
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

  <activity
      android:name="external.interfaces.Login"
      android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
  <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
  </activity>

  <receiver
      android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
      android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

          <category android:name="com.example.medicoappli" />
      </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
  <service android:process=":service" android:name="GCMIntentService"></service>
  ```
- GCMIntentService :

  ```
  package com.example.medicoappli;

  import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.widget.Toast;


  public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

  private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";                   

  public GCMIntentService() {
      super("329261430680");
  }


  private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {

      Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Vous avez un Messsage GCM", 3);
      toast.show();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onError(Context arg0, String arg1) {    }

  @Override
  protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

      Log.d("GCM", "RECEIVED A MESSAGE");
      Log.d("val", arg1.getStringExtra("val"));
      // Get the data from intent and send to notification bar
      //generateNotification(arg0, arg1.getStringExtra("message"));
  }

  @Override
  protected void onRegistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {    }

  @Override
  protected void onUnregistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {      }

  }
  ```

  - Server Side :

    ```
    package Server_Side;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import com.google.android.gcm.server.Message;
    import com.google.android.gcm.server.MulticastResult;
    import com.google.android.gcm.server.Result;
    import com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender;
    import java.net.Authenticator;
    import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;



    class Notify {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
    Sender sender = new Sender("AIzaSyDjIcQt6mff7ujIvqWtwKVuVEYmbUBy0I0");

        // use this line to send message with payload data
        Message message = new Message.Builder()
                .collapseKey("1")
                .timeToLive(3)
                .delayWhileIdle(true)
                .addData("message","this text will be seen in notification bar !!")
                .build();

        // Use this code to send to a single device (clé associé à l'application)
        Result result = sender.send(message,"APA91bGJxJxgtjmdKV1Ws766Cwr8ZaVKSn0Q7F17OQccI8sGhDWYo2pJCW0znS6qfEsy5ui1CSq9_ihGy9UKvoV9yqQW3AqP1c25ghLLBqt6nsPGEJE0qqHMhqIrhvVVDRy29R0gqtVZV-kJmicW5K8T_zOFO9reRUeADqTcxedKyjHhwFkxHOA",1);

        System.out.println(result.toString());

    } 
            catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

     }
     }
    ```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any code the registers your app to GCM and passes the registration ID to your server.

I don't see the point in starting the intent service in `onClick` :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, GCMIntentService.class);
intent.putExtra("val", "coucou");
startService(intent);
```

This service should only be started by `GCMBroadcastReceiver` when either a registration or a message arrive.

EDIT :

I would also change the service entry in the manifest from :

`<service android:process=":service" android:name="GCMIntentService"></service>`

to :

`<service android:name="com.example.medicoappli.GCMIntentService"></service>`

or at least :

`<service android:name=".GCMIntentService"></service>`

Comment: in fact, due to code clarity, i suppressed the part of code that did that. but the parameters used here in "new Sender()" and "result.send()" are already the results of the application registration to GCM. 
And, Concerning "GCMBroadcastReceiver", the "GCMIntentService" implements the onMessage function which should start the service, but it didn't. so, i thaught about starting it by self coding. it didn't work neither !

Comment: @NYassin What result do you get from Google at the server?

Comment: @NYassin If Google return a success response (with message id), see my updated answer for a suggested change in your manifest.

Comment: Here is the server response (Sout) : "[ messageId=0:1372234454309956%7f0e114400000031 ]".so i think that my server is OK and the message had really left this side but wasn't detected in my Android app. I tried also your edited code but it didn't work too.